# Refresh A Specific Sheet in Excel with C# in a SSIS Package

Tags: c#, excel, ssis

I've checked for similar questions, and they all seem to refresh ALL sheets, and generically.
I have created a SSIS Project in Visual Studio 2019.  I have many Excel files that I need to open and refresh.  They pull data from other sheets and SQL tables/views.  There is another sheet that then transforms/combines the data from all of the other sheets.  If I use the RefreshAll below I have to give it a time, and sometimes a sheet or two gets hung up for some reason and takes too long, and more often than not the consolidated sheet finishes before the last of the other sheets and is left incomplete.

In an ideal world I would be able to refresh each sheet, one at a time, and the finish with the consolidated sheet.  IDEALLY I could refresh all the individual sheets in parallel, and then the consolidated sheet would run last.  IDEALLY, I would not need specify a time and it would just complete when it's done.

I know that's a tall order.  I would be OK calling a script multiple times that takes the filename and sheet name, and refreshes that single sheet and does not require a time specified.  I was having a weird time passing the file path+name variable into the script, so I hardcoded mine.  I could not figure out how to refresh a SINGLE sheet though!

```
public void Main()
        {
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            ///string fileName = (string)Dts.Variables["$package::ExcelFileName"].Value;
            string fileName = @"C:\Master List (Consolidated).xlsx";

            Excel.Application m_objExcel;
            Excel.Workbooks m_objBooks;
            Excel.Workbook m_objBook;

            try
            {
                m_objExcel = new Excel.Application();
                m_objBooks = (Excel.Workbooks)m_objExcel.Workbooks;
                m_objBook = (Excel.Workbook)m_objBooks.Open(fileName,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing);
                Thread.Sleep(3000);

                m_objBook.RefreshAll();
                Thread.Sleep(10000);

                m_objBook.Save();
                m_objBook.Close();
                m_objExcel.Quit();

            }
            catch(Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("I am catching the error");

                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText("C:\\log\\" + "ErrorLog_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyMMddHHmmss") + ".log"))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                m_objBook = null;
                m_objBooks = null;
                m_objExcel = null;

                GC.Collect();
            }           
        }
```